# Show that for $N\ge2$, $\sum\limits_{k>N}2^{N!-k!}\leq\frac{1}{4}.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Show that for $N\ge2$, $$\sum\limits_{k>N}2^{N!-k!}\leq\frac{1}{4}.$$

I am not sure how I am supposed to interpret this inequality. I have tried telescoping it but didn't get any help with it. Also, I know that in general series of the form $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} 2^{-k!}$ converges to a real number between $0$ and $1$, but how do I use this result to prove this inequality? Does it even make any sense to approach this problem in this way? I can't really think about any elegant solution so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: $k!-N!=k!-(N+1)+ (N+1)!-N!$ $= k!-(N+1)!+N!\,N\ge k!-(N+1)!+4$ $\ge k-(N+1)+4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $N \geq 2$.

Let $n$ be a positive integer. If $k=N+n$, then we have
\begin{align*}N!-k! = N!-(N+n)!\leq N!-(N+n)\cdot \left(N!\right) &=N!-N\cdot \left(N!\right)-n\cdot \left(N!\right) \\&=(1-N)\cdot \left(N!\right) -n\cdot \left(N!\right) \\&\leq -2-2n\,.\end{align*}

This means we have $$\sum\limits_{k>N}2^{N!-k!}\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-2-2n}=\frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{16}\frac{4}{3}=\frac{1}{12}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: When $k > n$, the gap $k!-n!$ is very large. Indeed, $(n+1)!-n!=n!\cdot n\geq n$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I got stuck again at this step: $\sum\limits_{k>N}2^{N!-k!}\leq\sum\limits_{k>N}2^{-N}$. But how do I show that the sum on the RHS is less than $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: Geometric series or comparison test or write down the series for n=2,3